# Removing the spaces next to the line numbers in CLion

Tags: clion

Ho can I remove the spaces next to the line numbers in CLion?

[image]

It's just too much.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I don't believe you can change that, as that space is used for bookmarks, breakpoints, etc.

You could try `File->Settings->Editor->General->Appearance` and disabling 'Show line numbers', of course.